# Right angle triangle with an area of 41

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Can you find a right angle triangle with the shortest sides and whose area is equal to 41?
All sides have to be rational numbers.

---

HINT: The length of the hypotenuse is $44.05/3$

I hope this will help you to find the lengths of the other two sides of the triangle.

2nd HINT: You have the area and the length of the hypotenuse. Now I will give you the length of one of the two other sides, which is $6.15$

I hope now you can solve the puzzle.

Comment: Can you define "shortest sides". Is it shortest perimeter, shortest hypotenuse, or something else?

Comment: The minimum length of sides comprising this triangle.

Comment: You mean the minimum *sum* of length of sides, i.e. minimum perimeter? (If so, then I think ash4fun's answer is correct.) Or the minimum longest side, i.e. minimum hypotenuse? Or the minimum shortest side? For instance, does 10-24-26 have "shorter sides" than 12-16-20? (Perimeters are 60 and 48, hypotenuses are 26 and 20, but shortest sides are 10 and 12.)

Comment: The lengths are determined by the fact that their values create a right angle triangle with a specific area and cannot be longer or shorter. In addition, the answer will contain the specific lengths of the sides of the triangle, because that is the puzzle.

Comment: This is still unclear. What do you mean by "shortest sides". If two perpendicular sides are different, one side will be longer than the other. Do you mean "sum of the lengths being the minimum"? PS: btw, the hint given, this is no longer a puzzle. It's a matter of solving two simultaneous equations.

Comment: At this point, the "puzzle" involves proving that the known answer is unique (or at least is uniquely "shortest" in some sense), but that seems better suited for a math SO rather than this one.

Answer (score 3):

With the given hints, it is easy to find one such triangle.

> a = 123/20
>  b = 40/3
>  c = 881/60
>
>  It is the Pythagorean triple (369,800,881) divided by 60.
>
>  The area is a*b/2 = 41.

But ...

> There must be infinitely many Pythagorean triangles that are closer in shape to the (1,1,√2) triangle. So I don't think there is a "smallest" triangle in terms of lengths of the sides.

And yet...

> I ran a computer search and didn't find any other such triangle. So it seems the given triangle is the only and smallest triangle satisfying the conditions.
>  Update:
>  A new computer search found 2 other triangles, but they are very
>  asymetrical and therefore have a longer perimeter.

Comment: Typo on the area, it should be 41 instead of 42.

Comment: Yup.  Usually 42 sound just right...

Answer (score 2):

Solution incorrect; as noted in comments, scaling the area rationally is not the same as scaling the lengths rationally.

---

There is no such triangle.

For a triangle to have all-rational sides, it must be a rational multiple of a pythagorean triple. To determine the multiplier, simply take 41 divided by the original area of the triangle.

It is trivial to show that for a right triangle with given area, the perimeter is minimized by an isosceles triangle.

In the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2501300/363735), it is shown that an isosceles triangle cannot be made, but can be approximated to arbitrary precision by pythagorean triples.

Thus using sides of rational length, for any triangle we can always create a triangle closer to the minimum perimeter, but never reach the minimum.

Comment: Not sure this works. Aren't you missing a square root in the multiplier?

Comment: @ash4fun All three sides, each of different length, are rational numbers.

Comment: @loopy walt There are no square roots.

Comment: Okay, now I think I see what loopy walt was getting at: dividing an arbitrary triangle's area by x is equivalent to dividing both its length and height by sqrt(x), so just because a triangle is closer to isosceles doesn't mean it can be converted to area = 41 and still have rational side lengths.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Unless I've missed something there is no rational solution.</strike> Using $a$ and $b$ as the legs and $c$ as the hypotenuse:

A triangle's area is half the product of base and height, implying $ab=82$.

$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and since $b=\frac{82}{a}$, $c=\sqrt{a^2+(\frac{82}{a})^2}$.

$a$ is rational, so setting $a=\frac{x}{y}$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers and simplifying:

$c=\sqrt{\frac{x^4+82^2y^4}{x^2y^2}}$

In order for $c$ to be rational, the numerator and denominator of the fraction must both be perfect squares. The denominator is trivially already a square, so only the numerator needs checking. <strike>However, I ran this through WolframAlpha which says there are no integer solutions to the equation $x^4+82^2y^4=z^2$ except the trivial ones at $y=0$ (which is disallowed as $a=\frac{x}{y}$).</strike>

A solution for $x^4+82^2y^4=z^2$ is $x=40, y=3, z=1762$, corresponding to $a=\frac{40}{3}, b=\frac{123}{20}$ and $c=\frac{881}{60}$.

Comment: What about x=40, y=3 , z=1762?

Comment: @user82879 WolframAlpha usually only check small values if not specified, so it won't found the z=1762 solution.

Comment: While the answer is wrong, the approach is correct.  I suggest you fix your post to include the solution to to the last equation.

Comment: Thanks @franckvivien, updated answer to suit.